# EmberJS - throw error on `firebase` implementation

Tags: firebase, ember.js

In my `emberjs` - i am implementing the `firebase` data base. for that I have changed the `environment` settings like this: ( please see my comments )

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
    var ENV = {
        modulePrefix: 'ember-simple-blog-eee6c',
        environment: environment,
        rootURL: '/',
        contentSecurityPolicy: {
            'script-src': "'self' 'unsafe-eval' apis.google.com",
            'frame-src': "'self' https://*.firebaseapp.com",
            'connect-src': "'self' wss://*.firebaseio.com https://*.googleapis.com"
        },
        firebase: {
            authDomain: 'ember-simple-blog-eee6c.firebaseapp.com',
            databaseURL: 'https://ember-simple-blog-eee6c.firebaseio.com/',
            projectId: "ember-simple-blog-eee6c",
            storageBucket: "",
            messagingSenderId: "731960884482" //note sure taken from previous app
        },
        locationType: 'auto',
        EmberENV: {
            FEATURES: {
                // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
                // e.g. 'with-controller': true
            },
            EXTEND_PROTOTYPES: {
                // Prevent Ember Data from overriding Date.parse.
                Date: false
            }
        },

        APP: {
            // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
            // when it is created
        },

        contentSecurityPolicy: {
            'font-src': "'self' data: fonts.gstatic.com",
            'style-src': "'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com"
        }
    };

    if (environment === 'development') {
        // ENV.APP.LOG_RESOLVER = true;
        // ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = true;
        // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS = true;
        // ENV.APP.LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL = true;
        // ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = true;
    }

    if (environment === 'test') {
        // Testem prefers this...
        ENV.locationType = 'none';

        // keep test console output quieter
        ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = false;
        ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = false;

        ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
    }

    if (environment === 'production') {

    }

    return ENV;
};
```

After implemented this config, I am getting error as :

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember-simple-blog-eee6c/app` imported from `(require)`
```

What is wrong here? how to solve this? any one please help me .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have a duplicate of ContentSecurityPolicy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your firebase has nothing to do with your error. I'm able to recreate your error on my own app by giving `module-prefix` an incorrect name. Is it possible you are naming your `module-prefix` after your firebase project instead of your ember Project? If so, I think that might be the reason. I think you need your modulePrefix to have the same name as the folder your Ember project is inside of.

Comment: @3gwebtrain glad to hear it!

Comment: I am just  start to learn Ember. can you recommend some good tutorials please?

Comment: I still have a lot to learn myself. By far my favorite person who talks about Ember is Frank Treacy on EmberIgniter. He doesn't write tutorials but more just articles but it helps you understand the concepts really well.

Comment: Thanks. Let me look it.

Comment: They're just really good articles. He explains things very clearly. https://emberigniter.com/articles/